# xCode 9 crash during enterprise build

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, enterprise

When I want to export the app from the Organiser but every time xCode crashing during the export. I don't get any error archiving the app but only by creating the Enterprise export it crashes.

> Do you have any idea how to fix this?

```
Process:               Xcode [8747] Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode Version:               9.0.1 (13249) Build Info:    IDEFrameworks-13249000000000000~2 App Item ID:           497799835 App External ID:       823984564 Code Type:             X86-64 (Native) Parent Process:        ??? [1] Responsible:           Xcode [8747] User ID:               503

Date/Time:             2017-10-23 10:33:05.863 +0200 OS Version:       Mac OS X 10.12.6 (16G29) Report Version:        12 Anonymous UUID:     3E6AEA50-56B8-77D8-AF7A-31B673DB561F

Sleep/Wake UUID:       81D3789F-9478-43E1-8A03-149F3D41FDF4

Time Awake Since Boot: 23000 seconds Time Since Wake:       7500 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        9  Dispatch queue: ConcurrentQueue:
-[IDEDistributionPackagingStepViewController viewDidInstall]_block_invoke

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000007f8643ad060 Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11 Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

VM Regions Near 0x7f8643ad060:
    MALLOC_LARGE_REUSABLE  000000013aa28000-000000013b8f5000 [ 14.8M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--> 
    JS JIT generated code  0000409278e00000-0000409278e01000 [    4K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  

Application Specific Information: ProductBuildVersion: 9A1004
```

Comment: Already I have seen lots of questions related to same issue and the best possible solution is go for `Xcode 9.0.1` I am sure it will work.

Comment: I just updated to 9.0.1 and this crash still occurs.